# Run-time error '1004' Unknown PropertyId

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to excel and macros, but whenever I filter the pivot table to see the information for 3 out of 20 categories I as receive the

> "unknown property id"

message. The data is being pulled from another tab within the workbook. The line that is highlighted in the debugger is the Active Sheet line. Can you help me solve this problem?

```
    Sub PivotRefresh()
    '
    ' PivotRefresh Macro
    '
    Range("AA5").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
    End Sub


Sub RefreshAllPivotTables() 'Refresh Pivot Table
 Worksheets("FOUR").Activate
    For Each cache In ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches
    cache.Refresh 'Refresh Pivot Table      
    Next
End Sub

Sub Format_ws()
'
' Format_ws Macro
'

'

  Dim i As Long

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For i = 5 To Worksheets.Count
    With Sheets(i)
    Sheets("Template").Select
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(i).Select
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub



Public Function TabI(TabIndex As Integer, Optional MyTime As Date) As String
TabI = Sheets(TabIndex).Name
End Function
```

Comment: please indent the code by 4 spaces so that it shows up as code

Comment: delete the `range.select` line. you do not need to select any cell to refresh a pivot table  ..... change `activesheet.piv ....`   to the actual name of the worksheet `worksheets("sheet1").pivo ....`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to refresh a pivot table

```
Sub RefreshAllPivotTables() 'Refresh Pivot table
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    For Each cache In ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches
    cache.Refresh 'Refresh Pivot table
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The cache.Refresh line now has a 1004 error of application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: I just tested it and it ran fine for me. Where are you putting this code and where is the pivot table located?

Comment: please add the code to your question, and delete the two comments